# Calling JQuery Ajax Functions in Foreach loop - Need assitance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am currently studying programming and trying to build a website with .Net Core.
I have the following issue. I am not familiar with JavaScript that much and I have two JQuery/AJAX functions on my Index page. One of the function is for the posts likes/dislikes and the other for posts comments.

My ViewModel contains a collection of Posts:

```
    public IEnumerable<IndexPostViewModel> Posts { get; set; }

    public int PagesCount { get; set; }

    public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
```

Into my view I am looping through each Post and in it, through each Comment.

```
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
                    {
                        <div class="post-content">
                            <img src=@post.ImageUrl width="500" height="500" alt="post-image" class="img-responsive post-image" />
                            <div class="post-container">
                                <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="user" class="profile-photo-md pull-left" />
                                <div class="post-detail">
                                    <div class="user-info">
                                        <h5><a href="timeline.html" class="profile-link">@post.User.UserName</a> <span class="following">following</span></h5>
                                        <p class="text-muted">Post published at: @post.CreatedOn</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="reaction">
                                        <a class="btn text-green" href="#" method="post" onclick="sendVote(@post.Id, true)"><div class="icon ion-thumbsup" id="upVotes">@post.UpVotes</div></a>
                                        <a class="btn text-red" href="#" method="post" onclick="sendVote(@post.Id, false)"><div class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="downVotes">@post.DownVotes</div></a>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="line-divider"></div>
                                    <div class="post-text">
                                        <p>@post.Text</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="line-divider"></div>
                                    @foreach (var comment in post.Comments)
                                    {
                                        <div class="post-comment">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="" class="profile-photo-sm" />
                                            <p><a href="timeline.html" class="profile-link">@post.User.Email</a><i></i> @comment.Text</p>
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                    <form id="myForm" asp-controller="Comment" asp-action="Create" method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="PostId" id="postId" value="@post.Id" />
                                        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

And these are the functions in the Scripts section:

@section Scripts {

```
    function sendVote(postId, isUpVote) {
        var json = { postId: postId, isUpVote: isUpVote };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/api/votes",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(json),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#upVotes").html(data.upVotes);
                $("#downVotes").html(data.downVotes);
            }
        });
    }

    // wait for the DOM to be loaded
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function
        $('#myForm').each.ajaxForm(function () {
                alert("You have just posted a comment");
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
    });
</script>
```

}

My issue is that both functions are working correctly only for the first post. Can you please assist on how to modify the functions to be applied for each element in the loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove document location reload, are you using it to refresh your content? it will only run for the first, and then reloads everything,

Comment: Hello Ahmed,Yes, also tried without reloading and the first function for Likes/Dislikes does not reload the page, but still it is getting executed just for the first post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is simple. 
your selector and ids are not unique

id can only be defined for one element, same id on multiple/same elements will cause this issue.

the link tag has a common id for all records, it needs to be unique.

make the ids unique , i added @post.Id with ids, this will make each unique

```
                                <div class="reaction">
                                    <a class="btn text-green" href="#" method="post" onclick="sendVote(@post.Id, true)"><div class="icon ion-thumbsup" id="upVotes_@post.Id">@post.UpVotes</div></a>
                                    <a class="btn text-red" href="#" method="post" onclick="sendVote(@post.Id, false)"><div class="fa fa-thumbs-down" id="downVotes_@post.Id">@post.DownVotes</div></a>
                                </div>
```

and in you js  change the selector by adding id

```
function sendVote(postId, isUpVote) {
    var json = { postId: postId, isUpVote: isUpVote };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/votes",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(json),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $("#upVotes_"+postId).html(data.upVotes); // change here
            $("#downVotes_"+postId).html(data.downVotes);
        }
    });
}
```

---

and also for myform do the same, you dont need id for form, but if you want just add the @post.Id to id,

```
<form id="myForm" class="myform" asp-controller="Comment" asp-action="Create" method="post">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="PostId" id="postId" value="@post.Id" />
                                        <textarea name="text"></textarea>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Submit Comment" />
                                    </form>
```

and in event change id to class to make it dynamic,

```
 $('.myForm').each.ajaxForm(function () {
            // $(this)  will give you access to the specific form only
                alert("You have just posted a comment");
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
```

Comment: Hello Ahmed. Thank you very much for your clear explanations. Now I got it how it works. Fixed it and everything is working properly now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: glad it helped you. would appreciate if you also upvote it.

Comment: Unfortunately since I am a new user, up voting would not reflect on the post: Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.